# XPath to select by exact matches of children nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

Sample XML:

```
<cacheFile>
    <workflows>
        <workflow wfid="999" name="John" >
            <attached docid="001" />
            <attached docid="002" />
        </workflow>
        <workflow wfid="888" name="John" >
            <attached docid="001" />
            <attached docid="002" />
            <attached docid="003" />
        </workflow>
    </workflows>
    <otherData/>
</cacheFile>
```

As the snippet above shows, I've got an XML file containing data about various workflow items; each workflow element contains its own id, the name of the assigned worker and a list of attached document ids.  Using only the name attribute and list of document ids, I need to select the proper workflow id.

I came up with the following XPath query which almost works as intended:

```
//cache/workflows/workflow[@name='John' and ./document[@id='001'] and ./document[@id='002']]"
```

Problem is, this query returns both workflow items; I need it to return only the exact match (wfid=999).  There are dozens of ways to manually sort out the results, but I'm thinking there has to be some XPath function I haven't been able to find that could limit the results during query execution.  Perhaps a constraint to limit the number of child elements?

Comment: You cannot use the wifid?

Comment: there is no "document" tag, it is "attached".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the `attached docid` attributes:

```
x = """<cacheFile>
    <workflows>
        <workflow wfid="999" name="John" >
            <attached docid="001" />
            <attached docid="002" />
        </workflow>
        <workflow wfid="888" name="John" >
            <attached docid="001" />
            <attached docid="002" />
            <attached docid="003" />
        </workflow>
    </workflows>
    <otherData/>
</cacheFile>"""

import lxml.etree as et

xml = et.fromstring(x)


print(xml.xpath("//workflows/workflow[count(./attached/@docid) < 3]"))
```

Or maybe just counting the attached is sufficient:

```
"//workflows/workflow[count(./attached) < 3]"
```

You could use the doc values and make sure there are only 2:

```
xpath("//workflows/workflow[./attached[3]='' and ./attached[1]/@docid=001 and ./attached[2]/@docid=002]")
```

Of course if you could just use the wifid, it would be a lot simpler:

```
print(xml.xpath('//workflows/workflow[@wfid="999"]'))
```

Comment: The count() function did the trick, knew I was missing something simple...thanks a bunch!

Comment: No prob, you're welcome, there a lots of different ways to do it, it really just depends on what the constraints are.